# Mysql Table and Index Design for Dating Portal

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, solr, indexing

I am creating a dating portal where we will be asking user around 40-50 questions like religion,caste,date of birth,food preference,smoking/non smoking.

I am asking similar questions on the user preference like age range,religion preference,smoking preference.

I have around 30-40 such preference.

Now I want to show user the matches based on the preference set.
I want to know how I should design MySQL tables and indexes.

Should I create 1 big table of user_preferences and have all preferences indexes.
Should it be multiple column indexes or merge indexes.

Should I keep set of questions in different tables and join them when fetching the data?
m

Comment: Here's some discussion about [EAV](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back) - discussion starts at slide 16.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be a case for [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model):

[image]

You should be able to get the matching user pairs in the descending order (from most matching to least) similar to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT U1.USER_ID, U2.USER_ID, COUNT(*) MATCH_COUNT
    FROM USER U1
        JOIN USER_PREFERENCE P1
            ON (U1.USER_ID = P1.USER_ID)
        JOIN USER_PREFERENCE P2
            ON (P1.NAME = P2.NAME AND P1.VALUE = P2.VALUE)
        JOIN USER U2
            ON (P2.USER_ID = U2.USER_ID)
    WHERE U1.USER_ID < U2.USER_ID -- To avoid matching the user with herself and duplicated pairs with flipped user IDs.
    GROUP BY U1.USER_ID, U2.USER_ID
) Q
ORDER BY MATCH_COUNT DESC
```

This just matches the preferences by their exact values. You may want to create additional "preference" tables for range or enum-like values, and replace `P1.VALUE = P2.VALUE` accordingly. And you may still need special processing if the match is with the data in USER table (such whether user's age falls into other user's preferred age range).

Note the index on `{NAME, VALUE}` which is meant to help `P1.NAME = P2.NAME AND P1.VALUE = P2.VALUE`. InnoDB tables are [clustered](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/), and one consequence is that secondary indexes contain the copy of PK fields - which in this case causes the index `I1` to completely [cover](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index) the table. Whether MySQL will actually use it is another matter - as always look at the query plan and measure on representative data...

Answer (score 1):

I see something like this:

[image]

`questions` is the list of questions to be answered. `question_type` is an enumeration that indicates what type of answer is expected (e.g. lookup from `question_choices`, a date, a number, text, etc.) - whatever types of data you expect to be entered. This, along with the other columns in this table, can drive your input form.

`question_answers` contains a list of predefined answers to questions (such as a predefined list of religions, or hair color, or eye color, etc.). This can be used to build a drop-down list of values on your input form.

`users` is pretty self explanatory.

`user_characteristics` contains a list of my answers to the questionnaire. The `weight` column indicates how important it is to me that someone looking for me have this same answer. The `question_choices_id` would be populated if the answer came from a select list built from the `question_choices` table. Otherwise `question_choices_id` would be NULL. The converse is true for the `value` column. `value` would be NULL if the answer came from a select list built from the `question_choices` table. Otherwise `value` would contain the user's hand crafted answer to the question.

`user_preferences` contains answers to the questionnaire for who I am looking for. The `weight` column indicates how important it is to me that the person I am looking for have this same answer. The `question_choices_id` and `value` columns behave the same as in the `user_characteristics` table.

SQL to find my match might look something like:

```
SELECT uc.id
      ,SUM(up.weight)                   AS my_weighted_score_of_them
      ,SUM(uc.weight)                   AS their_weighted_score_of_me
      ,SUM(up.weight) + SUM(uc.weight)  AS combined_weighted_score
  FROM user_preferences        up
  JOIN user_characteristics    uc
    ON uc.questions_id           = up.questions_id
   AND uc.question_choices_id    = up.question_choices_id
   AND uc.value                  = up.value
   AND uc.users_id              != up.users_id
 WHERE up.users_id               = me.id
 GROUP BY uc.id
 ORDER BY SUM(up.weight) + SUM(uc.weight) DESC
         ,SUM(up.weight) DESC
         ,SUM(uc.weight) DESC
```

For performance reasons, an index on user_characteristics(id, question_id, question_choices_id, value, and user_id) and an index on user_preferences(id, question_id, question_choices_id, value, and user_id) would be advisable.

Note that the above SQL will return one row for EVERY user except the one making the request. This certainly is NOT desirable. Consequently, one might consider adding `HAVING SUM(up.weight) + SUM(uc.weight) > :some_minimum_value` - or some other way to further filter the results.

Further tweaks might include only returning people who value an answer as much or more than I do (i.e. their characteristic weight is >= my weight preference weight.